# Backbone update model if its already exist in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to implement basic cart on backbone.js I'm completely new in it.`itemsListView` adds object to `cartCollection`. Problem is that when model is added in collection I want to increment this model quantity attribute if this model already exist in `cartCollection`.

```
 var Phone = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var PhonesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Phone
});
var itemListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    collection: null,
    _template: _.template($('#listTemplate').html()),
    el: $('#phonesDiv'),
    events: {
        'click .buyButton': '_addToCart'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        'use strict';
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        'use strict';
        var rendTemplate = this._template({items: this.collection.toJSON()});
        this.$el.html(rendTemplate);
        return this;
    },
    _addToCart: function (e) {
        'use strict';
        var buttonId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
        var result = this.collection.findWhere({id: buttonId});
        var purchase = {
            id: result.attributes.id,
            name: result.attributes.name,
            price: result.attributes.price
        };
        cartcollection.add(new cartModel({
            id: buttonId,
            item: _.pick(purchase, 'id', 'name', 'price'),
            itemTotalPrice: purchase.price
        }));
        console.log(cartcollection);
    }
});
```

cartModel and cartCollection:

```
var cartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: null,
        item: {
            id: null,
            name: null,
            price: null
        },
        itemTotalPrice: 0,
        quantity: 1
    }
});
var cartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: cartModel,
    defaults:{
        totalQuantity: 0,
        totalPrice: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a method to your collection class. Here's one way to do it, with a method I'm calling `addToCart`:

```
var cartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    quantity: 0
  }
});

var cartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: cartModel,
  addToCart: function (model) {
    this.add(model);
    var q = model.get('quantity');
    model.set('quantity', q + 1);
  }
});
```

When you call a Backbone collection's `add` method, if the model you use as an argument is already in the collection, it will not be added again. Then, you can just increment the model's quantity manually.

The code below shows how this would work; you can [play with it in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vivaduyuwi/edit?js,console).

```
var m1 = new cartModel({ name: 'm1' });
var m2 = new cartModel({ name: 'm2' });

var cart = new cartCollection();

cart.addToCart(m1);
cart.addToCart(m1);
cart.addToCart(m2);

console.log('cart length:', cart.length); // 2

console.log('m1 quantity:', m1.get('quantity')); // 2
console.log('m2 quantity:', m2.get('quantity')); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function() {
        
        var cartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                 id: null,
                 item: "",
                 quantity: 1
            }
        });
        var cartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: cartModel
        });
        // sample data
        var data = [{id: 1, item:"testA"}, {id: 2, "item":"testB"},  {id: 1, "item":"testA"}, {id: 1, "item":"testA"}]
        var cart = new cartCollection();
        for(i in data){
            var item = data[i];
            // check if item already exists in collection
            var model = cart.get(item.id);
            if(model){
                // increment model's quantity by 1
                var quantity = model.get("quantity");
                model.set("quantity", ++quantity);
                // remove the model from collection and add updated model 
                cart.remove(item.id);
                cart.add(model);
            }else{
                // if model doesn't exist in collection
                // simple add it to collection
                cart.add(item);
            }
        }
        console.log(cart);
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```